# Show all starting distinct element after a filtering and group by

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my starting dataframe:

**salesDf**

| itemName | sales_quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 200 |
| Apple | 400 |
| Pear | 300 |
| Pear | 500 |
| Banana | 300 |

```
salesDf.where(col('sales_quantity') > 300)\
       .groupBy(col('itemName')).agg(sum(col('sales_quantity')))
```

| itemName | sales_quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 400 |
| Pear | 500 |

but I would like something like this

| itemName | sales_quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 400 |
| Pear | 500 |
| Banana | 0 |

or even better

| itemName | sales_quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 400 |
| Pear | 500 |
| Banana | 0 |
| Pineapple | 0 |

Can I explicit in the grouped column the values I want to show?
Thanks

Comment: sorry, bad translation.. by the way, i would insert a new value not present in the starting df

Answer (score 2):

You can sum over a masked `sales_quantity` using `when` and `otherwise`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = salesDf.groupBy('itemName').agg(
    F.sum(
        F.when(
            F.col('sales_quantity') > 300, F.col('sales_quantity')
        ).otherwise(0)
   ).alias('sales_quantity')
)

result.show()
+--------+--------------+
|itemName|sales_quantity|
+--------+--------------+
|  Banana|             0|
|    Pear|           500|
|   Apple|           400|
+--------+--------------+
```

To add a new row you can do a `union`:

```
result = salesDf.groupBy('itemName').agg(
    F.sum(
        F.when(
            F.col('sales_quantity') > 300, F.col('sales_quantity')
        ).otherwise(0)
   ).alias('sales_quantity')
).union(spark.sql("select 'Pineapple' , 0"))
```